# Why are my online parameters always lost?

Tags: ps3, assassins-creed-brotherhood

*Almost** each time I play online, I have to set again all my profiles, which are empty and the colors/equipments of the characters. It's highly annoying. I don't get how this can be that these settings are sometimes saved and sometimes not.

(*)  I was not able to pinpoint when it works and when it doesn't. I quit the game properly before switching off the console. There are no network issue when it happens.

Do you also experience this issue?
Is there a way to be sure that the configuration will be saved and retrieved the next I go to play online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found this on Ubisoft forums:

> This is a known problem with the game that the developers are currently investigating.  In the meantime, please try this workaround:
>
> - Login to multiplayer and set up your profile.
> - After setting up the profile, logout of multiplayer and start a single player game.
> - Save the game in singleplayer, then log back in to multiplayer mode.
> - Your profile should now be saved correctly.

<strike>I didn't try the workaround yet as I'm too addicted to the multiplayer mode right now. I'll try this later and accept the answer if it works.

I put it here anyway. Who knows if it can be of any help in the meantime!</strike>
Tried the workaround which didn't work for me... :(
Let's wait for a patch then.